# Laravel middleware order

Tags: laravel

I have a few custom middlewares defined in `App\Http\Kernel.php`, after the ones that ship with Laravel:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

        // Custom Middleware
        'custom1' => \App\Http\Middleware\Custom1::class,
        'custom2' => \App\Http\Middleware\Custom2::class,
        'custom3' => \App\Http\Middleware\Custom3::class,
    ];
```

In `Custom1` I use `auth('web')->user()->id` which gives the error `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`.

This error happens sometimes, not always, in my production environment and it's difficult to figure out why.

My guess is that the user is not authenticated for some reason (session expired?). If that's the case then I'm wondering why the auth middleware doesn't catch this.

Further down in the Kernel file there is:

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
```

Could it be that the `Custom1` middleware is executed before the auth middleware and should I add it at the end of `$middlewarePriority`?

Comment: Hello @eskimo can you please add your route file?.

Comment: @BabalolaMacaulay no need anymore, I forgot to apply the auth middleware to some routes...